# regex to get all selector which have hex color code in its block but choose only one not all color

Tags: javascript, css, regex

requirement: collect all color codes ( in hex format for now) from a CSS document along with their selector.

below is the sample css document

```js
const cssDcoument = `

body {
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #222;
}

main {
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.class, .other {
    color: #333;
    font-size: 20px;
}

`;
```

1. using below regex I am able to get all the color code from css document

```js
const rgx = /(?<color>#[0-9a-f]{3,6})/;
```

[working demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/r3d0tn78/1/)

2. now need to capture their repective selector used below regex which combine the above regex also in it

```js
const rgx = /([.#]?[\w, .:]+?)(?= \{[^}]+?(?<color>#[0-9a-f]{3,6})[^}]+?\}.*)/;
```

[working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xkeshav/gt1k0u9n/1/)

but issue is with above regex is that it only capture the first hex value property from one block not all like the first regex does.

here only select `#111` but not `#222` from `body` selector

what can be done here to get all color code ?

Comment: What is the expected result based on your CSS example? Please add the desired resulting object or array

Comment: it must select all color code from file like first regex does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for blocks with rules first, then for particular colors:

```js
const css = `
    body {
      padding: 2px;
      background-color: #111;
      color: #222;
    }

    main {
        margin: 20px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .class, .other {
        color: #333;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    `;

const matches = css.matchAll(/^\s?(.+)\{([^}]+|\s+)}/gm);
for (const match of matches) {
    console.log("selector",  match[1].trim());
    const block = match[2].trim();
    console.log(block.match((/#([a_fA-F0-9]{3,6})/g)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine but in this case `block`  turns into one line separated by `/r/n` while my main declaration block was separated with new line in multiple lines. how to get the original declaration block.

Comment: @diEcho `\r\n` IS a line break... It's just that your debugger is showing you the string as a typical literal with `''` or `""`.

Comment: yeah but issue here is the block changed for each selector but I need index refrence from main text file

Comment: @diEcho What do you mean by "block changed"? This code gives you all selectors and all colors in its block. 'block' string in this code is anything between curly brackets. If this is not a solution to your original problem, then you should elaborate expected output more in the question.

Comment: I agree with you completely that my initail problem solved by your solution but yes have subsequent problem.  there is index mismatch which I am telling. 
when we run `css.matchAll((/#([a_fA-F0-9]{3,6})/g))` (i.e. from whole ccc doument then index of slected element is diffrent when we apply the same regex with `block.matchAll()` which is obvious because whole document length and content is diffrent from block, but I want here that index comes from the same index somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex to get color specifically

```
^\s*color\:\s*\#[a-fA-F0-9]+
```

To get any line with color in it:

```
color\:\s*\#[a-fA-F0-9]+
```

positive lookbehind

```
(?<=color)\:\s*\#[a-fA-F0-9]+
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for color hex not based on `color` literal, it may be inside `background` or `border` property too